# Sharepoint 2010 list and alerts

Tags: list

I have created an issue list in sharepoint 2010, we have created teams as one of the fields.  How would i make sharepoint send alert notificaitons to certain email groups based on the team selected?

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a public view for each team with a filter to select items marked with the team
2. Create an alert for each team specifying the e-mail address of the team and in "Send Alerts for These changes" specify "Someone changes an item that appears in the following view:" and select the teams view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send notification to a specific security group after creation of an issue for a specific team, Alert Me might not be a good choice. better you go for sharepoint designer workflow to send mail to a specific group or user. In this case you can enable targeted audience from library settings of the list and provide the targeted groups in targeted audience field. Then you would be able to access it from workflow. Let me know if you need further informations...

Answer (score 0):

You may also be able to use an Alert filter (in an alert template) to do this.  Check out this link: (although the link references WSS 3.0, it should still apply to 2010)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/07/customizing-alert-notifications-and-alert-templates-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0.aspx